# SQL - how to query the most recent value of a column within a larger result set

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this schema containing the source data

```
CREATE TABLE `sourceData` (
  `eventDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `eventType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `eventDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `visitorId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `acountId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `eventCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minutesOnPage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `urlParameter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `visitorIpAddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `eventDomain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vistorUserAgent` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventDate`,`eventId`,`visitorId`,`accountId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Using this data, I want to create another table containing the latest value of eventDescription for each eventId. I have created the following query to get this result:

```
SELECT max(eventDate) as maxEventDate, eventDescription, eventId 
FROM sourceData 
GROUP BY eventId, eventDescription 
ORDER by eventId;
```

My expected result for this was that there would only be 1 record for each eventId. However, I am getting multiple records for each eventId. Any suggestions on how I can adjust my query to get my desired result?

```
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| maxEventDate | eventDescription                                                     | eventId                     |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2019-06-25   | Settings - User Settings - New Password                              | _2SkneHp0dkIlHef52uPRGKaf34 |
| 2019-06-10   | Settings - User Settings_New Password                                | _2SkneHp0dkIlHef52uPRGKaf34 |
| 2019-06-21   | User Settings - New Password                                         | _2SkneHp0dkIlHef52uPRGKaf34 |
| 2019-06-04   | Offer Tab_Makegood Missed Spots - Preempt(s)_Show All Buyer Demos    | _3YDY4OVlw-L2OVSZruGcwATEcI |
| 2019-06-27   | Campaign Performance Details - Spot Detail - Back to Top             | _4_61DOJgg2J6y0wGleGeu30J4w |
| 2019-06-21   | Spot Detail - Back to Top                                            | _4_61DOJgg2J6y0wGleGeu30J4w
```

Comment: You are grouping on `eventDescription` but the value for that is different on each row, so it won't roll up to a single row.  Trying selecting `MAX(eventDescription)` and removing it from your `GROUP BY` if you don't care which description is displayed.  If you do care, then update your source data to have a single description for each `eventId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a join with subquery for max eventdate

```
select * 
from sourceData s 
inner join  (
  SELECT max(eventDate) as maxEventDate,eventId 
  FROM sourceData 
  GROUP BY eventId 
  ) t on t.maxEventDate = s.eventDate and t.eventId = s.eventId
```

and if you need  distinct result add DISCTINCT clause

Answer (score 0):

if your dbms support row_number() then you can try like below

```
 select * from (SELECT *,
row_number() over(partition by eventId order by eventDate desc) rn
 FROM sourceData ) a where a,rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select sd.*
from sourceData sd
where sd.eventId = (select sd2.eventDate
                    from sourceData sd2
                    where sd2.eventId = sd.eventId
                    order by sd2.eventDate desc
                    limit 1
                   );
```

This particular formulation assumes that event dates are unique for each event id.  And for performance, you want an index on `(eventId, eventDate desc)` -- well, the `desc` if possible.